# Tkinter image slideshow, defining the image folder path inside new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a slideshow with Python3 & Tkinter. It works fine, but only if I define the path to the image folder inside the code. But the people I am going to share this program with don't know how to edit the code. So, I want another Tkinter window that pops up when you start the program, then asks you to define the path to your image folder. You copy and paste the path (of your image folder) into a text box inside the tkinter window. I will put my slideshow code underneath.

CODE:

```
import tkinter as Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random
import glob

class GUI:
    
    def __init__(self, mainwin):
        self.mainwin = mainwin
        self.mainwin.title("Our Photos")
        self.mainwin.configure(bg="yellow") 
        self.counter = 0
        
        self.frame = Tk.Frame(mainwin)
        self.frame.place(relheight=0.85, relwidth=0.9, relx=0.05, rely=0.05)

        self.img = Tk.Label(self.frame)
        self.img.pack()

        self.pic_list = glob.glob("/home/maheswar/Pictures/*")
        self.colours = ['snow', 'ghost white', 'white smoke', 'gainsboro', 'floral white', 'old lace',
            'linen', 'antique white', 'papaya whip', 'blanched almond']
            

        self.colour()
        self.pic()
        
    def colour(self):
        selected = random.choice(self.colours)
        self.mainwin.configure(bg=selected)
        root.after(4000, self.colour)

    def pic(self):

        filename = self.pic_list[self.counter]
        image = Image.open(filename)
        
        real_aspect = image.size[0]/image.size[1]
        width = int(real_aspect * 800)  
        
        image = image.resize((width, 800))
        
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.img.config(image=self.photo)
        

        self.counter += 1
        
        if self.counter >= len(self.pic_list):
            self.counter = 0

        root.after(2000, self.pic) 

root = Tk.Tk()
myprog = GUI(root)
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.mainloop()
```

### Edit:

This is the full working code for those who wish to try:

```
import tkinter as Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random
import glob
from tkinter import filedialog

    
class GUI:

    def __init__(self, mainwin):


        self.mainwin = mainwin
        self.mainwin.title("Our Photos")
        self.mainwin.configure(bg="yellow") 
        self.counter = 0
        
        self.frame = Tk.Frame(mainwin)
        self.frame.place(relheight=0.85, relwidth=0.9, relx=0.05, rely=0.05)

        self.img = Tk.Label(self.frame)
        self.img.pack()

        #self.pic_list = glob.glob("/home/maheswar/Pictures/*")
        directory = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=mainwin, title='Path asker',
                                      initialdir='/home')
        self.pic_list = glob.glob(f"{directory}/*")
        self.colours = ['snow', 'ghost white', 'white smoke', 'gainsboro', 'floral white', 'old lace',
            'linen', 'antique white', 'papaya whip', 'blanched almond', 'bisque', 'peach puff',
            'navajo white', 'lemon chiffon']

        self.colour()
        self.pic()
        
    def colour(self):
        selected = random.choice(self.colours)
        self.mainwin.configure(bg=selected)
        root.after(4000, self.colour)

    def pic(self):

        filename = self.pic_list[self.counter]
        image = Image.open(filename)
        
        real_aspect = image.size[0]/image.size[1]
        width = int(real_aspect * 800)  
        
        image = image.resize((width, 800))
        
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.img.config(image=self.photo)
        

        self.counter += 1
        
        if self.counter >= len(self.pic_list):
            self.counter = 0

        root.after(2000, self.pic) 

root = Tk.Tk()
myprog = GUI(root)
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `askdirectory` with `tkinter`:

```
from tkinter import filedialog


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, mainwin):
        ...

        directory = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=mainwin, title='Title of the box',
                                      initialdir='path/of/initial/directory')
        self.pic_list = glob.glob(f"{directory}/*")
```

**Note:** If you are looking to pick up images, then you can add extensions to your `glob`, like `glob.glob(f"{directory}/*.png')` and this will choose all PNG images inside the `directory` instead of all the files.

[Read more on `askdirectory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory)

Comment: Note that [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) is the name of a Python built-in so I would suggest using another name for the variable — `directory` maybe?